# Exported eclipse preferences contain \!/=

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I exported the preferences from an eclipse product to compare them with my `plugin_customization.ini` file. The first two lines of the exported `*.epf` file are the following:

`#Wed Jul 25 10:59:27 EEST 2018
\!/=`

What is the meaning of `\!/=`?
I noticed it also in the `plugin_cusotomization.ini` file which I maintain, but it is present at the middle of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the name of the node in the Eclipse preferences (`IEclipsePreferences`) for this preference save.

`!` specifies that this is a preferences node definition (the preceeding `\` is just a properties file escape). `/` is the path for the root node. The property has no value.

Code for this is in `org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService`

```java
private static final char EXPORT_ROOT_PREFIX = '!';
private static final float EXPORT_VERSION = 3;
private static final String VERSION_KEY = "file_export_version"; //$NON-NLS-1$

public IStatus exportPreferences(IEclipsePreferences node, OutputStream output, String[] excludesList) throws CoreException {

    ... other code

    properties = convertToProperties(node, excludesList);
    if (properties.isEmpty())
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    properties.put(VERSION_KEY, Float.toString(EXPORT_VERSION));
    properties.put(EXPORT_ROOT_PREFIX + node.absolutePath(), EMPTY_STRING);
```

Comment: As a safe measure, should I add this setting in the `plugin_customization.ini` on the first line or it wouldn't matter?

Comment: I have never used it in plugin_customization.ini so I don't think it is useful there.